# Need to make a 2x2 ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data:

```
   unigrams   Freq
1       the 236133
2        to 154296
3       and 128165
4         a 127434
5         i 124599
6        of 103380
7        in  81985
8       you  69504
9        is  65243
10      for  62425
11       it  60298
12     that  58605
13       on  45935
14       my  45424
15     with  38270
16     this  34799
17      was  33009
18       be  32725
19     have  31728
20       at  30255
```

and this set of data:

```
    bigrams  Freq
1    of the 20707
2    in the 19443
3   for the 11090
4    to the 10939
5    on the 10280
6     to be  9555
7    at the  7184
8    i have  6408
9   and the  6387
10    i was  6143
11     is a  6114
12    and i  5993
13     i am  5843
14     in a  5770
15   it was  5644
16    for a  5343
17   if you  5326
18    it is  5196
19 with the  5092
20   have a  4936
```

I would like to place two qplots together side-by-side, ncol = 2.  I tried the gridExtra library, but it is generating errors that I can't seem to figure out how to correct.  Any ideas on how to do this, please?

```
library(gridExtra)
# The 20 most unigrams in the dataset
ugrams <- as.data.frame(unigrams)
graph.data <- ugrams[order(ugrams$Freq, decreasing = T), ]
graph.data <- graph.data[1:20, ]

p1 <- qplot(unigrams,Freq, data=graph.data,fill=unigrams,geom=c("histogram"))


# The 20 most bigrams in the dataset
bgrams <- as.data.frame(bigrams)
graph.data <- bgrams[order(bgrams$Freq, decreasing = T), ]
graph.data <- graph.data[1:20, ]

p2 <- qplot(bigrams,Freq, data=graph.data,fill=bigrams,geom=c("histogram"))

grid.arrange(p1,p2,ncol=2)
```

This is the error that is generated:

```
<error/rlang_error>
stat_bin() can only have an x or y aesthetic.
Backtrace:
  1. (function (x, ...) ...
  2. ggplot2:::print.ggplot(x)
  4. ggplot2:::ggplot_build.ggplot(x)
  5. ggplot2:::by_layer(function(l, d) l$compute_statistic(d, layout))
  6. ggplot2:::f(l = layers[[i]], d = data[[i]])
  7. l$compute_statistic(d, layout)
  8. ggplot2:::f(..., self = self)
  9. self$stat$setup_params(data, self$stat_params)
 10. ggplot2:::f(...)
```

I would like to have the graphs resemble this one:

[image: The FourGrams Histogram]

Which was accomplished by the following code:

```
# The 20 most quadgrams in the dataset
qgrams <- as.data.frame(quadgrams)
graph.data <- qgrams[order(qgrams$Freq, decreasing = T), ]
graph.data <- graph.data[1:20, ]
ggplot(data=graph.data, aes(x=quadgrams, y=Freq, fill=quadgrams)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 40, hjust = 1))
```

Is that possible

Comment: Without sample data it's a bit difficult. Have you considered `facet`ing it instead? If not, perhaps `cowplot` or `patchwork` packages could work.

Comment: @r2vans, I edited the question with data for you to take a look.  Please let me know how I can ged rid of that error and generate the two plots side by side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edited** for your shift from histograms to bar plots. Assuming that `graph.data` is actually your `ugrams` dataset, the working single plot is

Putting them side-by-side can be done with facets:

```r
dplyr::bind_rows(
  unigrams = select(ugrams, grams = unigrams, Freq),
  bigrams  = select(bigrams, grams = bigrams, Freq),
  .id = "id") %>%
  arrange(-Freq) %>%
  mutate(
    id = factor(id, levels = c("unigrams", "bigrams")),
    grams = factor(grams, levels = grams)
  ) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = grams, y = Freq, fill = grams)) +
  facet_wrap(~ id, ncol = 2, scales = "free_x") +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 40, hjust = 1))
```

[image: ggplot2 facets, with free "x" axis]

(Obviously, these are "too small" to hold all of the legend, but that depends on where you are using it. I wonder if the legend shouldn't be included, since it is somewhat redundant with the x-axis labels.)

The y-axis on the left is harder to see because it is dwarfed by the unigrams on the right. While it does bias the plot (it might be natural to compare the vertical levels of the plot on the left with those on the right), you can alleviate that by `free`ing both the "x" (already free) and "y" axes with `scales="free"`:

[image: ggplot2 facets, with both axes free]

Comment: I edited my question to reflect the way that I have the graph now, as a single ggplots.  Having them one by one takes too much space, so I wanted to have six of them lined-up 3x3, or four of them, lining-up, 2x2, but I can't seem to be able to use the grid.arrange to do it without getting the error.  I sure do hope that I can achieve it.

Comment: I updated the plots here, but I don't think it addresses your concerns. Is your concern about the legend size, the x-axis spacing, or something else?